# “Value is not a valid member of model” error, when it 100% is

Tags: lua, roblox

So, I’m trying to make it so when a player claims a tycoon, the number of the tycoon is saved in an intvalue that gets parented to their character. There is a button that *should* only function if the player owns the tycoon it is in. The value is name “Tycoon”. When I try to do

```
local click = workspace.Button1.ClickDetector

click.MouseClick:Connect(function(player)
    if player.Character.Tycoon.Value == 1 then
        …
    end
end)
```

the game throws me an error:
“Tycoon is not a valid member of Model “Workspace.PlatinumAdventurer(my user)””

When I run the project, I can see that the intvalue is 100% in the character.
I have tried using :waitforchild, but it doesn’t work. I’ve also tried to, instead of doing `player.Character`, doing

```
local playerName = player.Name
…
if workspace.playerName.Tycoon.Value…
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you?

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with the model structure.

You can try checking if player has a character first, then find the IntValue`Tycoon` parented to the character. Once the IntValue is found, it should retrieve it's actual value and perform action if `tycoonValue == 1`

```
local click = workspace.Button1.ClickDetector

click.MouseClick:Connect(function(player)
local character = player.Character
if character and character:FindFirstChild("Tycoon") then
local tycoonValue = character.Tycoon.Value
if tycoonValue == 1 then
...
end
end
end)
```

Comment: I have tried this already - thank you though.

Comment: Can you try the updated code and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I tried your code and found that the issue is happening because, APPARENTLY, Tycoon is not part of the character, when it clearly is -  I think this is beyond my abilities to solve…